# Can't use "Follow symbol under cursor" multiple times on functions in other files

Tags: qt-creator

Qt creator (v. 4.5.2) behaves strange when I use the "follow symbol under cursor" feature (shortcut is F2) on a function that is declared in a different file. It works perfectly the first time, but when  I try to use the feature again on the same function or a function in the same file, nothing happens, not even an error message appears. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly check that all the files in question are logically apart of the project, either in files directly in the project or in files included from folders listed as include folders in the project

This could be an issue with interesting folder paths. I have had similar behaviour when my source directories are under several levels of symbolic links and the first use of F2 takes me to a file not in my current project so it then doesn't know how to find the rest of the code any more. This will also show up as apparently multiple copies of the file being open. Another symptom will be file saves overwriting different changes.